# Extend Session Expiry Time

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, session-state

I am running a discussion website. The problem that is coming is that after sometime session automatically expires. I am hosting my website on a shared server and doesn't have access to the settings of extending expiry time in IIS. So is there any way I can do that using web.config?

And also I enabled basic authentication on the server and using default authentication in my website, means I didn't gave any authentication mode in configuration file. So are they same?

Comment: you can use form authentication mode to avoid session expiry issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="x" />
    <system.web>
</configuration>
```

Where x is the desired session timeout in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage session timeout using web.config

Sessionstate timeout property is mentioned in minutes.

In webconfig file...

```
   <system.web>
<sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```